# Twitter bootstrap - constrain dropdown height

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap in a project, and would like to contrain the height of the dropdown menu.

This seems to work fine in Chrome and IE. However, in FF the vertical scrollbar does not seem to be active, even though its visible - I cant seem to click on the actual scrollabr

See http://jsfiddle.net/P65cs/ for an example

Comment: which version of FF are you using?

Comment: just upgraded to FF10 and getting the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to solve the issue:

```
.navbar .dropdown-menu:before {
    content:normal;
}
```